# Sample size for ordered logit model

Tags: sample-size, ordered-logit

Is there any rule of thumb or formula how to calculate sample size for ordered logit model?

Comment: Perhaps http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.4780122404/abstract will help you.

Comment: @mdewey I found this but unfortunately, I don't have access to it.

Comment: Try putting the title into your favourite search engine where you may find other references.

Comment: @mdewey I did some research and I found formula when you have two groups - treatment and control. In my case there is only one group with five categories. Any suggestions please?